# What should be returned?

Tags: c++

I am new to the programming so I don't know how to describe the problems encountered precisely.

Here is the declaration of the function

```
 vector<int>& operator>>(vector<int>& v, int& x){

   }
```

I am just wondering what should be returned for this function.
I am trying to implement the operator >> for the vector class if that is relevant at all to my question.

Thanks for the help

Comment: For the record the operator `>>` is not an extraction operator, but rather a bit shift operator which has been used for other things. Perhaps if you describe what you expect the operator to do then we could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you're probably trying to chain operations: `vec >> int1 >> int2;`. That means you should return the first parameter so that it can be used in the next call.

```
vector<int>& operator>>(vector<int>& v, int& x){
        x = v.back();
        v.pop_back();
        return v;
   }
```

Comment: @user3444882 I think you already know how to do the large code sample. For the smaller one you just encase the code with a single back tick ``` on either end. I hope that comes out OK in this comment.

Comment: hmm seems to be complicated. Anyway I get the code to compile and everything. But I am not entirely sure if I test the code correctly. Inside of my main function, I have  ` int x = 0; v >> x ` with v being defined as a vector somewhere else in the main function.

Comment: @user3444882 do it twice like I did in my example. `v >> x >> y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int>
```

Should be returned. If you return `vector<int>&` then you can't return a new vector, else it will be destroyed going out of scope when the function finishes and the reference will be invalid. If you return the inputted vector `v` then you will need to mofify it, which is unwise.

Comment: This line of code is actually given in the assignment by the instructor of my programming class.